Relationship between hessian matrix and curvature
I am taking vector calculus this semester, and while researching about Hessian matrices for a project, I encountered this formula.
enter image description here
Could anyone explain how it is derived, or its meaning? f seams to be a 2-variable scalar function, and I cannot visualize it in my head.

Welcome to math SE. Have a look at mathjax to typeset the mathematical expression

This is a formula for Gaussian curvature, which is a concept in differential geometry that applies to smooth surfaces. If you want good intuition for how curvature works and how it relates to the Hessian, it will be helpful to introduce some geometry concepts.
We're used to considering shapes on the Euclidean plane, which has no curvature. That is, $\kappa=0$ at every point. Instead consider a sphere, which is a surface that lies in 3-space and contains all the points that have the same distance from the origin. This is like the surface of the Earth. If you formed a triangle on Earth by picking 3 different cities and drawing the shortest path between them, the triangle wouldn't have straight lines because of the Earth's curvature. The lines would instead be arced away from the triangle's center, and the sum of its angles would be greater than $\pi$ radians (180 degrees). This is because spheres have positive curvature at every point. On the other hand, a triangle on a saddle with negative curvature would look a little like a three-pointed star, so the sum of its angles would be less than $\pi$ radians. From Wikipedia:


Points that "look like" maxima have positive curvature, and points that "look like" saddles have negative curvature. The curvature doesn't have to be constant across the entire surface, either. Here is a torus. Try to picture what a triangle would look like in each section.

Glossing over the details, but the easiest way to analyze a surface is to map subsets of it to $\mathbb{R^2}$ and then pass those through functions like $f:\mathbb{R^2}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$.
Now let's finally turn back to your formula, which as you said deals with 2-variable scalar functions like these:
$$\kappa=\frac{det(H_f)}{(1+f_x^2+f_y^2)^2}$$
The numerator includes the Hessian of $f$, which as you probably know is a matrix of the second partial derivatives. This allows us to use a multivariable version of the second derivative test to classify the critical points of $f$ where $\nabla{f}=(0,0)$. A critical point can be classified using the eigenvalues of the Hessian:

If both eigenvalues of the Hessian (which, in the case of a critical point, turn out to be the principle curvatures at the point) are positive, then the point is a local minimum. Informally, if everything is curving upward around this point, it must be a minimum.
Similarly, if both eigenvalues are negative, then the point is a local maximum.
Otherwise, the principal curvatures point in different directions, so the point is a saddle.

Since we are dealing with a 2x2 Hessian with 2 eigenvalues $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$, we can use the fact that the product of the eigenvalues of a matrix equals its determinant. Since $\det(H_f)=\lambda_1\lambda_2$, a positive determinant must indicate a local extremum with positive curvature. Whether it is a minimum or a maximum is irrelevant; the curvature is positive either way, and triangles in a neighborhood of this point will have angles that sum to greater than $\pi$. By the same logic, a negative determinant indicates a saddle with negative curvature. So, for a critical point, $\kappa=\det(H_f)$.
If the point is not a critical point, the Hessian still gives us information about curvature even if we cannot classify any critical points. In this case, some normalization is required to account for the (now non-zero) gradient of $f$. This is where the first partial derivatives in denominator come in. However, since it the denominator is always positive, this will never affect the sign of $\kappa$.
To summarize, the Hessian is essentially like a multivariable second derivative test that can also be used to determine curvature even on non-critical points.

Thank you so much. I know nothing about differential geometry, and this helped me a lot.
